# Change in date of birth in passport

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, legal, india

My correct date of birth is 19/09/1993.While taking admission in school due to the staffs negligence they made it 19/06/1993.Also my father ignored it considering it won;t create any issue.Now my school leaving certificate and other documents(pancard,addhar card etc.) has date of birth as 19/06/1993.
My passport has my real date of birth 19/09/1993 as per birth certificate.
And i want to get it changed to 19/06/1993.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: To be clear, are you asking if you can change your passport to state a false date of birth?

Comment: You want to use false date of birth on an identity document. Don't do this. You will get in a lot of trouble and for a very bad reason. If you ever try to get a visa it could come up and you could get banned. Really, why would you even try?

Comment: @Tushar Patel What is stopping you from getting the other documents changed to show the correct date to match your birth certificate and passport?

Comment: Are you serious? This is bizarre.

Comment: I can't think of any country where this is not a crime. The best thing that could happen is that you simply get banned from any country you try to visit. The worst possibility is that you end up in prison.

Comment: Even if you get passport "corrected", your birth certificate will still show the old DOB so correct course (as suggested by people here) is to get all other documents changed. I would suggest starting from school records and then moving to other documents.

Comment: thank you all..it was opinion/consequences i was needed due to this.would proceed with changing correct date of birth to other documents.

Answer (score 7):

The correct course of action here is to change the document(s) that are *wrong*, not to change the documents that are *correct*.

I understand that changing all the various identity documents in India to read the correct date might be more difficult than changing your passport, but changing your passport to have the wrong date is inadvisable.